# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm running a Laravel application it shows the following error:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>>'$.country' as country FROM country' at line 1 (SQL: SELECT name->>'$.country' as country FROM country)`

The query is

```
$countrylist = DB::SELECT("SELECT name->>'$.country' as country FROM country");
```

The `name` field is a JSON field, its structure is as follows:

```
{"country": "US", "currency": "USD"}
```

and I am fetching the name from it with my query.

Comment: Please share the relevant code to your problem.

Comment: This is a misspelled, share your code

Comment: It is running on another PC. It looks strange..! Here is the code: 

$countrylist = DB::SELECT("SELECT name->>'$.country' as country FROM country");

Comment: Share your sql build `$country = Country::...` or `$country = DB::table('countries')->...`.

Comment: The name field is a json field, it's structure is as follows: {"country": "US", "currency": "USD"} and fetching the name from it by query.